VsCode Terminal Issue
I am having issue with Vs Code terminal while running code Installed in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
The output is getting printed before .enter image description here

Not really an Ubuntu or a VSCode issue, rather a programming one. Just add a cout << endl; after printing the array. This will print a new line after you've printed your array and the prompt will be below it as you expect.
